# How do I make the scanner function of my HP Photosmart d110 work?

Tags: hp, scanner

I recently switched from windows to ubuntu and my all in one print/copy/scanner can only print now. I want to scan some documents.

Comment: Wireless or USB connection?

Comment: I am having a similar problem with an 8600 all-in-one, and it seems that HPLIB is (temporarily) not supported in the latest version of UBUNTU (14.10)

Comment: did you try the app, "Simple Scan"?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [out](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/photosmart/photosmart_d110_series.html). These are HP Linux drivers and this page is for your model printer. Apparently these drivers are open source as well.