# HP Photosmart Premium C410b / Ubuntu / scanner function

Tags: wireless, drivers, printing, hp, scanner

Is there an easy way to make the scanner function of my HP Photosmart Premium C410 work in Ubuntu 14.04?

The printer is connected by Wifi through a wireless router.

The basic printing function works perfectly through >System Settings>Printers where the printer driver was set up however, the scanning features are not shown to be available, only the print queue and basic settings.

The following links I have found provide no solution:

[How do I make the scanner function of my HP Photosmart d110 work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178766/how-do-i-make-the-scanner-function-of-my-hp-photosmart-d110-work)

[Wifi connection to scanner not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214175/wifi-connection-to-scanner-not-working)

I have checked compatibility with the HP website and both Ubuntu 14.04 and the printer are compatible with each other. It suggests that the hplip version version downloaded with v14.04 will be the currently available one.

It all works perfectly fine from a laptop (Windows 7) on the same router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scan mechanisms and print mechanisms in Ubuntu are seperate, as opposed to the methods used on some other OSs.

For Ubuntu, the basic included scan program is Simple Scan, which can be found by opening the Dash and typing `sane` or `simple scan`, or opening a terminal and entering `simple-scan`

There are additional programs which can be downloaded to build upon the capability of the simple-scan program.  These can be found in the Ubuntu Software Center